# Weird deadlock due to RemoveParticipants in C#'s Barrier Class

Tags: c#, barrier

I came up with a very weird deadlock when using C Sharp's Barrier. The intention is to see how `RemoveParticipants()` actually works. I started with 2 threads (2 actions), each performs `barrier.SignalAndWait();`. Afterwards, one thread will remove one participant. Since this point, the barrier count is only 1. By right, all remaining `barrier.SignalAndWait();` should go through without any deadlock. However, the below program is deadlocked.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class BarrierDemo
{
    /* Print out barrier's phase and count */
    static void printInfo(int action, Barrier b){
        Console.WriteLine("action {0} : phase = {1} ; count = {2} ",action, b.CurrentPhaseNumber, b.ParticipantCount);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2);

        Action action1 = () =>
        {
            printInfo(1,barrier);

            barrier.SignalAndWait();

            //Thread.Sleep(1000);

            printInfo(1,barrier);

            barrier.SignalAndWait();

            printInfo(1,barrier);

            Console.WriteLine("action 1: terminating");
        };

        Action action2 = () =>
        {
            printInfo(2,barrier);

            barrier.SignalAndWait();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("action 2 : wake up 1 ");
            barrier.RemoveParticipants(1);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("action 2 : wake up 2 ");
            printInfo(2,barrier);

            barrier.SignalAndWait(); // **DEADLOCK HERE**

            printInfo(2,barrier);
        };

        /* Execute 2 actions in parallel */
        Parallel.Invoke(action1,action2);

        Console.WriteLine("Going to dispose");
        barrier.Dispose();

    }

}
```

The output I received when tracing is:

```
action 1 : phase = 0 ; count = 2
action 2 : phase = 0 ; count = 2
action 1 : phase = 1 ; count = 2
action 2 : wake up 1
action 1 : phase = 2 ; count = 1
action 1: terminating
action 2 : wake up 2
action 2 : phase = 2 ; count = 1
[Deadlock]
```

Another note is that if I commentize all System.Sleep() in action2 and decommentize the System.Sleep() in action1. Then the program terminates:

```
action 1 : phase = 0 ; count = 2
action 2 : phase = 0 ; count = 2
action 2 : wake up 1
action 2 : wake up 2
action 2 : phase = 1 ; count = 1
action 2 : phase = 2 ; count = 1
action 1 : phase = 2 ; count = 1
action 1 : phase = 3 ; count = 1
action 1: terminating
Going to dispose
```

I am not sure why the above program deadlocks? Why `action2` stops at the `barrier.SignalAndWait();` while it is supposed to pass (the barrier count is only 1)?

Thanks for viewing and any help.

> **Summary of solutions:**
>
> This problem is platform-dependent. I got the deadlock due to running it on non-native platforms. I tried it using 2 online compilers (1) http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php, (2) https://compilr.com/ and got the deadlock. The first only compiler uses mono to execute windows executable (which is non-native). I am not sure about the platform of the second online complier.
>
> However, as suggested by `Phillip Scott Givens` and `svick`, I installed and ran the example natively on Visual C# 2010 running .Net 4.0 and the deadlock disappeared.

Comment: I have copied your code into a unit test and it works fine for me. Here is my output every time I run it (sorry that I cannot format this comment): 
  action 1 : phase = 0 ; count = 2 
  action 2 : phase = 0 ; count = 2 
  action 1 : phase = 1 ; count = 2 
  action 2 : wake up 1 
  action 1 : phase = 2 ; count = 1 
  action 1: terminating
  action 2 : wake up 2 
  action 2 : phase = 2 ; count = 1 
  action 2 : phase = 3 ; count = 1 
  Going to dispose

Comment: I even changed the commenting on task 1 & 2 as you say and it works you say. Very strange. I have not used Barriers, but now you have confirmation that your code works on someone's computer.

Comment: I'm not getting the deadlock. But it is possible that's because I'm on .Net 4.5.

Comment: Thanks for your information, Phillip Scott Givens and svick. I tested it on Visual Studio 2010 with .Net 4.0 and cannot reproduce the deadlocks. I may conclude that the problem arises on non-native platforms.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens Just so you know, you can format code in comments by surrounding the code with ` marks.